# Open facebook login screen in landscape mode in ios

Tags: iphone, facebook, landscape

I am developing an app in landscape mode. I have a "Login with facebook" button which will redirect to facebook page asking to login to the user. My problem is ,when I tap "login with facebook" button the orientation changes and facebook page opens in portrait mode...What should I do so that facebook page also should open in landscape mode after tapping "login with facebook" button.?? Help will be aprreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fix it? I am also facing same issue, Please let me know what is the fix for this issue?

Comment: No..its in that way only

Comment: Then How you are doing? You posted t last year may right? DId you find any alternative for that?

Comment: No..left it the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to force the Facebook login dialogs to a specific orientation, this is due to being designed and optimized for portrait mode.

Comment: Correct. Try to look at it this way, not all ui's can be displayed in landscape, simply due to the nature of it (possibly the same goes for your app in portrait mode).

Comment: It means that if my app is running in landscape mode but when facebook login is done in safari then, it will open in potrait mode only?

Comment: From Landscape view I opened facebook login page in safari. safari opens in potrait mode. Now when it come back to app from safari it display the User Interface in potrait mode. How to display the UI back in landscape mode. Please help.